# Validate signed assertion embedded in SAMLResponse

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, xml-signature, opensaml

I work with OpenSaml library, I want to validate signed assertion (XML Signature) embedded in SAMLResponse that is not signed. Always the validation fail, there are a way to validate the signed assertion without his parent (Response) ? Or, another another way to do it ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185569/how-to-validate-a-saml-signature-value

Comment: I could validate an assertion not embedded in samlResponse, but the problem when it is embedded, the validation fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here that when I sign the assertion, the id of the signature is referenced to the Response and not to the assertion. So, I fix this by referencing the id of the signature to the assertion and not to the response. see [here](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf)  (page 71, section 5.4.2)